# How to use function instance of reader monad?

Tags: haskell, monads

I have found an interesting use of this monad:

```
Prelude Control.Monad> liftM2 (,) head tail $ [1..5]
(1,[2,3,4,5])
```

It looks like useful technique that allows `r` in `(->) r` to be passed only once, where I would expect this expression to require duplicating the list first.

I don't quite understand how lifting actually works here. Where is `>>=` or `return` hidden? What are other common situations which would call for using this particular instance?

Comment: Note that the preferred solution would be `(head &&& tail)` with the fanout combinator from `Control.Arrow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Read [freyrs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20768160/766752) first; this answer expands upon it.)

See [the defintion of the reader/Function monad instance](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#fmap)

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where
  return = const
  f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r
```

You can see there where the input gets duplicated/forked (`r` appears twice on the right-hand-side of the `\ r` expression): Each value that is passed to `(>>=)` (both `head` and `tail`, in your example) is then passed the same argument (`[1,..5]`) when the combined (monadic) function is applied to that argument.

Without using monadic `liftM2`, the (function application) expression `(,) head tail` just creates a tuple `(head, tail)`. But when (as in `liftM2`) monadic bind is applied instead of "plain" function application, those arguments are bound ("bind-ed") into the monadic value, where they remain "ready" to receive the bind result's function argument.

Note also that the final argument (`r = [1..5]`) is used once for each call to `(>>=)` (which happens twice in `liftM2`, that's what the `2` means). The `return` causes no additional use of the final argument, since in this monad we have `return f r = const f r` (`f r` added for explicitness), which ignores the argument `r`.

Answer (score 2):

`liftM2` takes a binary function and two monadic values and applies the function over the values inside the monad. Look at the implementation:

```
liftM2 :: (Monad m) => (a1 -> a2 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m r
liftM2 f m1 m2 = do 
  x1 <- m1
  x2 <- m2
  return (f x1 x2)
```

Or if we desugar it we can see the explicit `(>>=)` and `return`:

```
liftM2 :: (Monad m) => (a1 -> a2 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m r
liftM2 f m1 m2 = 
  m1 >>= (\x1 ->
  m2 >>= (\x2 ->
  return (f x1 x2)))
```

This is useful whenever you have a need to apply a pure function inside a monad, the use cases are pretty wide since it's a very common task.